# Is it possible to have multiple APK support according to countries in google play?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an application that changes according to country and language.
So I am planning to publish apk based on the countries.
Is it possible to have multiple APK support according to countries in google play?

Comment: afaik there's no possible way you can do it ,If you want the app to work according to country you need to do that in your app

Comment: Check [Filters](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html)

Comment: Try filters as @hrskrs suggested.